# Recovering a RAID5

Tags: debian, raid, software-raid, mdadm

Hoping somebody here can help, as I'm a bit stuck on what to try next.

Essentially, I had a RAID5 of 4 disks in `mdadm`. One of the disks started failing, not enough to have `mdadm` eject it, but enough to affect the server.
So I physically removed the drive and rebooted the server. On boot, I get a message about needing to run an `checkdisk` interactively (which makes sense, as the server became unresponsive several times due to the failing disk) and drops me into a shell, but the keyboard doesn't work (num-lock flashes each time I press a key, but no output. Works fine in BIOS and GRUB).
I started a live environment and installed `mdadm` onto it, which found and assembled the RAID. But running `fsck` from there complains about an invalid super-block.

I've still got the failed drive (didn't do anything that stupid) but I'm not sure how to go about recovering the data. Could there be an LVM on the RAID that's stopping fsck? And if so, how would I bring it online in the live environment?

Thanks!